# ZF2 caching menu with ACL

Tags: menu, zend-framework2, acl

I have a navigation menu into which I'm putting the ACL tree. That's working fine.

The navigation tree is growing larger and I notice performance getting a little sluggish with all of the isAllowed calls. I would like to cache the menu by user. While I can write my own view helper to achieve, I suspect it's likely that this is available through standard functionality. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: [By ZF2 document](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.permissions.acl.advanced.html), ACL objects may be **serialized** with PHP‘s serialize() function, so I think that your choice is correct way. BTW, I'm working in the same way.